# How to disable Marble Kde tiles movement

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, marble

I load in marble map a .jpg image refered by .kml file:

```
marbleWidget->model()->addGeoDataFile(kmlpath);
```

The image is loaded in marble map: with the mouse I can move (drag and drop) and resize the jpg into the map.
How can I anchor at specified coordinate or better, disable mouse interaction?

Other data like [this] (https://techbase.kde.org/Marble/Runners/LoadingKML)
are locked on map.

Comment: Maybe Marble::AbstractFloatItem::positionLocked ( )  can be useful, but I don't know how to use it
https://zivo.kde.org/marble/html/classMarble_1_1AbstractFloatItem.html#aa26cb945f3e518df0953065e96297c54

Comment: The same problem:
https://www.mail-archive.com/marble-devel@kde.org/msg03879.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//disable Annotation rendering in order to lock ground overlay movement
for (auto rp : this->renderPlugins())
{
    if(rp->name() == "Annotation")
        rp->setVisible(false);
    qDebug() << rp->name();
}
```

where "this" is the instance of your class:

```
    class Yourclass:  public MarbleWidget
```